# About the meaning of a due date

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

If someone says "applications due January 12" are they including that day also (until 23.59.59h)  o do they really mean strictly **before** that date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of an in-person business transaction, it usually means it must be received before the end of that business day (the due date).

If it is something mailed, like an application, it needs to be received in the mail before or on that date.
Mail is usually only delivered once a day, so it has to be ready to be delivered before the end of the day.

If the due date is not a normal business day (such as a weekend or holiday), then it needs to be received by the last business day before the due date.

Comment: There are subtle differences how various organisations handle this: I used to work for the German tax office and we had to use 23:59 un any given due date. This would lead to us accepting mail that was posted in our post box until up to two days later. Example: The office closes at friday afternoon, If this was the due date, we would accept all mail we'd find when opening the mailbox the next monday ca. 6:30. But better safe than sorry....

Comment: @Stephie Tax day might be an exception (Apr. 15 in the US). The government is more interested in getting their money...

Comment: No, not because of "we want the money", but because you can't shorten a (legal) deadline just because you want to go home ;-) At least, that's how the pro's stated it. And if you can't prove it was there after the deadline, you have to assume it was on time.

Comment: @Stephie I was just kidding, sort of. Anyway, in the US it is usually stated as "needs to be postmarked by ...", so as long as someone is there to do that, you are OK.

Answer (score 3):

[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/due?showCookiePolicy=true) states:

> If something is due at a particular time, it is expected to happen or to arrive at that time.

So, yes, the day itself is *included*.

Comment: But it does *not* say that it's a good idea to wait until "due date, 23:59" ^_^

Comment: as long as the possibility exists... :P

Comment: And I guess before is ok as well. :D

Answer (score 0):

For job applications etc, helpful advertisers (companies/people) include a time (and maybe time zone) with the due date: 'applications close 5 pm Eastern Australian Summer Time (UTC +11) on 12 January', especially when people from different countries might be applying. Otherwise, I would assume close of business (usually 5 pm) rather than 23.59. 
In any case, it is always possible and always safe to send your application to arrive (at least) *the day before* the due date, though this is not always possible.